# insert then select scope_identity() generates duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, database

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[table] (
  [column1] int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  [column2] int NULL,
  [column3] int NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([column1])
);
INSERT INTO schema.table (column2,column3) VALUES (1,1);
SELECT scope_identity();
```

it inserts TWO identical rows, and returns the primary key for the second inserted row.

It is probably a very basic reason, but google is not my friend on this one.

Comment: Any triggers on that table? It certainly won't happen with just the code you've given here.

Comment: it seems that it comes from the way EMS SQL Manager works. Doing it in my Delphi application works, and even doing it in separate statements in EMS (insert - execute - select scope_identity() - execute), so it's EMS' fault and not SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please copy and paste verbatim

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE dbo.[table] (
  [column1] int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  [column2] int NULL,
  [column3] int NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([column1])
);
INSERT INTO dbo.[table] (column2,column3) VALUES (1,1);
SELECT scope_identity();

SELECT * FROM dbo.[table]
```

You should get

```
---------------------------------------
1

column1     column2     column3
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
```

When in doubt, always try on a clean new table in tempdb.

Other notes:

- If you are running insert from ASP.Net, check whether you have CSS elements (background image link) that is blank, it causes a 2nd request to the same page
- If you are running just a plain INSERT in SSMS or similar tool, check for triggers

To find triggers against a table using TSQL

```
select name, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
from sys.objects
where type='TR'
and OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'table'  -- or whatever the table name is
```

To view the text of a trigger (or any module) using TSQL

```
select definition
from sys.sql_modules
where object_id = object_id('tg_table')  -- or whatever the trigger is named
```

Comment: +1 for the CSS background image check. That was my first thought to.